# Facebook Login and OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth, facebook, openid-connect

Can someone confirm whether Facebook Login API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2) is based on OpenID Connect (http://openid.net/connect/) specification?

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: Posted here since found some discussion about OpenID Connect here. Agree that it is off topic, will move it to SO.